# physics: determine velocities of 2 spheres after collision

Tags: math, physics, collision

I'm using [Physics for Games Programmers](http://books.google.com/books?id=oVLDoO-V67cC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Physics%20for%20Game%20Programmers%20grant%20palmer&source=bl&ots=pAeGfdNJBH&sig=Ucf8zj2LFUZY9iBgjDu6-rjXvn4&hl=en&ei=sNiYTdDnLYfagQeJjvG0CA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) to develop a simple physics-based game.

I need to compute the resulting velocities for two spheres after an elastic collision. The book example for this in Chapter 6 assumes that the 2nd sphere is stationary, and so some of the equations are simplified to 0. I need the math to work when both bodies are in motion.

I've tried to convert the book's example to code, and puzzle out what should happen for the second sphere's line of action and normal- V2p and V2n. My code sort of works, but occasionally the velocities suddenly speed up and bounce out of control. Clearly there's something wrong with my math.

Here's what I'm using. The code is in Java, "s1" and "s2" are the spheres.

```
    double e = 1d;

    // distance of sphere centers
    double dX = s2.getCenterX() - s1.getCenterX();
    double dY = s2.getCenterY() - s1.getCenterY();

    double tangent = dY / dX;
    double angle = Math.atan(tangent);

    // v1 line of action
    double v1p = s1.getVelocityX() * Math.cos(angle) + s1.getVelocityY() * Math.sin(angle);

    // v1 normal
    double v1n = -s1.getVelocityX() * Math.sin(angle) + s1.getVelocityY() * Math.cos(angle);

    // v2 line of action
    double v2p = s2.getVelocityX() * Math.cos(angle) + s2.getVelocityY() * Math.sin(angle);

    // v2 normal
    double v2n = -s2.getVelocityX() * Math.sin(angle) + s2.getVelocityY() * Math.cos(angle);


    double v1massScale = (s1.getMass() - (e * s2.getMass())) / (s1.getMass() + s2.getMass());
    double v2massScale = ((1 + e) * s1.getMass()) / (s1.getMass() + s2.getMass());

    // compute post-collision velocities
    double v1pPrime = v1massScale * v1p + v2massScale * v2p;
    double v2pPrime = v2massScale * v1p + v1massScale * v2p;

    // rotate back to normal
    double v1xPrime = v1pPrime * Math.cos(angle) - v1n * Math.sin(angle);
    double v1yPrime = v1pPrime * Math.sin(angle) + v1n * Math.cos(angle);

    double v2xPrime = v2pPrime * Math.cos(angle) - v2n * Math.sin(angle);
    double v2yPrime = v2pPrime * Math.sin(angle) + v2n * Math.cos(angle);
```

Comment: maybe you'll have some more luck here : http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

It might be the `Math.atan(y/x)`.  You need to handle some special cases, and you usually want to use `Math.atan2(y,x)` instead.

See the [Math.atan()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan%28double%29) and [Math.atan2()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2%28double,%20double%29) docs.

Answer (score 1):

It's a surprisingly difficult problem if you don't know much about physics or math.

You need to know about Newton's laws of motion.  These are couple differential equations, so you'll need to know how to solve those.

The problem is easier if you assume certain things to be unimportant for the behavior you're interested in: rigid versus deformable spheres, friction, and other factors.

The answer depends a lot on what you'd like to do.

A quick glance at the code you posted suggests that the best you can hope for is that you have a correct but less than optimal implementation.  It's likely that you fail to understand the physics and mathematics sufficiently well to solve it on your own.

I'd Google for a physics engine in the language of your choice and use an idealization that someone else has already coded.

Comment: Yeah, you said it. Last time I used this kind of math+physics was about 18 years ago. :-) The book got me about 80% of the way there. I also tried using AndEngine (the app is to run on Android) but 1) there's a rather large cognitive load in figuring out how use a generalized physics engine (I wasn't planning on using OpenGL, for example) and 2) it seems somewhat hackish the way they integrate with Box2D.

Comment: And BTW, no disrespect intended toward the AndEngine folks- I know they have good reasons for doing things the way they did, but it doesn't dovetail well with my current aims. I haven't ruled it out entirely though, but I'd like to see if I can do things simply first.

Comment: The thing that makes a "simple" problem like billiard balls difficult is that at the point of impact you need to transform to a coordinate system that has one unit vector between the centers of the balls and two others orthogonal to it.  You calculate the components of velocity in that coordinate system and then transform those back to the (x, y, z) coordinates that you know and love.  So your formulation is going to be helped if you use vectors and proper transformations to calculate each component.  It's not trivial.